# Having issue with extending JavaScript class in another JavaScript file - GULP

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I am creating a simple to-do list project. In that, I have two HTML files and two javascript files.

1. index.html <---> script.js
2. todoDetails.html <---> todoDetail_script.js

In my script.js I have a class called "Store" for all local storage methods.

```
class Store{

    static getTodos() {
        let todos;

        if(localStorage.getItem('todos') == null) {
            todos = [];
        }
        else {
            todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
        }

        return todos;
    }

    static addTodos(todo) {
        const todos = Store.getTodos();
        todos.push(todo);
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    }

    static removeTodo(taskName){
        const todos = Store.getTodos();

        todos.forEach((todo, index) => {
            if(todo.task === taskName)
            {
                todos.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    }

    static showTodoDetail(taskName){
        window.location = 'todoDetail.html?taskName=' + taskName;
    }
}
```

In my todoDetail_script.js I wanted to extend a "Stroe" class to access "getTodos()" method.

```
class UI1 extends Store {
    static displayTodolist() {
       
        const todos = Store.getTodos(); 

        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        var taskName = urlParams.get('taskName');


        todos.forEach((todo) => {
            if(todo.task == taskName) {
                document.getElementById('task_name').value = todo.task;
                document.getElementById('priority').value = todo.priority;
                document.getElementById('due_date').value = todo.duedate;
                document.getElementById('task_status').value = todo.status;
            }
        });
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',UI1.displayTodolist());
```

I am struggling with linking script.js with toDetails_script.js. script.js has many other classes too. I just want to import script.js file in toDetail_script.js.

I tried GULP. I don't know which npm gulp dependency will help me to resolve this.

Does somebody know how to help?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? How did you import `script.js`? Is this running on browser environment?

Comment: Make sure you import script.js with `type="module"` inside the other js file

Comment: I tried GULP,  Installed gulp-import dependency using npm and written import code in gulpfile.js but it just imports script.js code in todoDetail_script.js, and forms this as a single file named todoDetails_script.js in a destination folder.

Comment: I am opening HTML file directly in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to do a couple of things

first you need to add export default in front of the Store class

```
export default class Store{

static getTodos() {
    let todos;

    if(localStorage.getItem('todos') == null) {
        todos = [];
    }
    else {
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    }

    return todos;
}

static addTodos(todo) {
    const todos = Store.getTodos();
    todos.push(todo);
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
}

static removeTodo(taskName){
    const todos = Store.getTodos();

    todos.forEach((todo, index) => {
        if(todo.task === taskName)
        {
            todos.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });

    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
}

 static showTodoDetail(taskName){
     window.location = 'todoDetail.html?taskName=' + taskName;
 }
}
```

then in the todoDetail_script.js you need to write at top

```
import Store from 'here write the path to script.js'
```

then in todoDetail_script.js you can use the

```
Store.getTodos();
```

also in the html file where you are including this toDetail_script.js besides src attribute add the `type="module"` attribute as well.

Note: This is an ES6 module feature and would only work on localhost or a webserver and will not work if you directly open the html in browser.

For creating a webserver you can use this chrome extension

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb/related?hl=en
```

Comment: When i do this i received this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"

Comment: You are correct i am trying to open directly the html file in browser. Is there any other possibility to do this with adding any extension. I tried GULP, in that i was done the "npm install gulp-imports" but it doesn't help me. It just concate two files and thank you for your indetail explanation which help me a lot.

Comment: @priya Can you include the script.js in the todo html file if that's ok then we can make it run pretty simply ?

Comment: My motive is not to include script.js inside todoDetail.html. It contains only todoDetail_script.js.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said above but I received the error " Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './script.js' does not provide an export named 'Store'". I included import statement in todoDetail_script.s like "import { Store }  from './script.js';"

Comment: @priya dont use the curly braces when importing Store, simply write Store without them and then try.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience in guiding me. If I give without curly braces it works well but my doubt is it includes the entire script.js file. it runs all the classes and methods at the start. So it gives a lot of errors like can't set property to a null reference. So what I did is,I included some if statements, Is this the right way?

Comment: One better way would be if you could create separate class for getTodos() method and then extend that for Store, like this you can import only the new class and not the whole Store class but this again depends on your functionality so if you could do this it will be a bit cleaner and concise then some if statements.

Comment: @priya If this answer helped you can you please mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my quick test I found it easier to create an object of the class. So in the todoDetail I will create an instance of Store: var miniStore = new Store(), and then you can call the methods of Store using miniStore like: miniStore.addTodos(x)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `todoDetail_script.js` is executed before `script.js`, so when your page loads you should be getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Store is not defined` in your console.

The quickest way to fix that would be to use `defer`to ensure that your files are executed in the correct order.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).

Try this:

```
<script src="path/to/your/js/files/script.js" defer></script>
<script src="path/to/your/js/files/todoDetail_script.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: I have written script tag in two different HTML file and I am running this on localhost. particularly it is not an ES6 module. how will we import script.js in todoDeatil_script.js?

Comment: @priya I never mentioned ES6 modules. You can a) use 2 script tags in your HTML files as shown above or b) use a tool like gulp, npm, yarn etc to combine all files in one. The fastest way is go to for option a. The most maintainable one is to go for b.

Comment: thank you. I tried GULP, in that, i was done the "npm install gulp-imports" but it doesn't help me. It just concate two files. Is there any other GULP dependency that will help me to just import script.js in todoDetail_script.js? What i need is I need to include import(script.js) in top of todoDetail_script.js to access the class any particular class of script.js file.